# How to Avoid Group By when using MIN Or Max in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

I am trying to generate a report  only by getting first in & Last out by using the `Min` & `Max` functions in SQL Server with the Device Name. My problem is when I call the device name (EDailyEvents.EDevName) it will show multiple times for the same guy if he punched multiple times. When I need only one entry with first In & Last Out. Below is the simple query which I'm trying to use.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EToken,
    EDailyEvents.EName,
    Emaster.EDesig,
    EDailyEvents.EDevName,
    MIN(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time In',
    MAX(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time Out'
FROM
    EDailyEvents
INNER JOIN EMaster ON
    EDailyEvents.EToken = EMaster.EToken
GROUP BY
    EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EToken,
    EDailyEvents.EName,
    Emaster.EDesig,
    EDailyEvents.EDevName
```

Comment: share sample data and its output and database name

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read (and write.)

Comment: `As 'Time In'`  is invalid (standard) SQL to begin with. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: The title of your post is somewhat confusing. I cannot imagine you don't want to use grouping (using GROUP BY) as you say in the title, because as I understand from the post description, you definitely want to do so.

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin, Added the sample data. for highlighted employee. it shows multiple entries as he punched in deferent devices.

Answer (score 0):

first in

```
Select top 1 Distinct
EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
EDailyEvents.EToken,
EDailyEvents.EName,
Emaster.EDesig,
EDailyEvents.EDevName,
Min(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) As 'Time In',
Max(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) As 'Time Out'
from
EDailyEvents

Inner Join EMaster on EDailyEvents.EToken=EMaster.EToken
group by
EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
EDailyEvents.EToken,
EDailyEvents.EName,
Emaster.EDesig,
EDailyEvents.EDevName
order by 1
```

last out, order desc

Comment: Hmmm. Why do you use a DISTINCT in combination with a GROUP BY? Normally, all groups returned from a GROUP BY query are already "unique". And why do you return only the first row (TOP 1)? Perhaps you want the first EPunchDate value, but you can have multiple results (for different EToken, EName, EDesig and/or EDevName values) for those as well... Which one will be the correct one?

Comment: @Bart Hofland, Yap, Distinct Is not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get other first in / last out values, you should tweak your "group fields".

In this case you create groups based on these values:

- EDailyEvents.EPunchDate
- EDailyEvents.EToken
- EDailyEvents.EName
- Emaster.EDesig
- EDailyEvents.EDevName

So yes, there is a chance that there are multiple groups with duplicate values. You might have multiple groups with the same EName value, but with different EDevName values. Or reverse: with the same EDevName value, but with different EName values.

If you want more general groups, for example if you don't need to be specific about EToken and EName values, you should just leave those "unnecessary" group fields out. Like in the following query:

```
SELECT
    EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EDevName,
    Emaster.EDesig,
    MIN(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time In',
    MAX(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time Out'
FROM
    EDailyEvents
INNER JOIN EMaster ON
    EDailyEvents.EToken = EMaster.EToken
GROUP BY
    EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EDevName,
    Emaster.EDesig
```

That way, you get less groups (but with more data in each group, causing corresponding different results for aggregate functions like MIN and MAX, of course).

Another example: if you don't want create different groups based on different tokens and different device names, you could leave out those fields instead. Like this:

```
SELECT
    EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EName,
    Emaster.EDesig,
    MIN(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time In',
    MAX(EDailyEvents.EPunchTime) AS 'Time Out'
FROM
    EDailyEvents
INNER JOIN EMaster ON
    EDailyEvents.EToken = EMaster.EToken
GROUP BY
    EDailyEvents.EPunchDate,
    EDailyEvents.EName,
    Emaster.EDesig
```

With these examples, I assume you can now easily create the groups you actually need in your end results.